# Find the flaw in the proof

Tags: induction

Find the error in the proof.

This is the question:

Theorem: Every positive integer is equal to the next largest positive integer.

Proof: Let $P(n)$ be the proposition that $n=n+1$.To show that $P(k)$ implies $P(k+1)$, assume $P(k)$ is true such that $k=k+1$. Adding 1 on both sides we get $k+1=k+2$. Which is nothing but $P(k+1)$. Thus, $P(k)-P(k+1)$ is true. Hence $P(n)$ is true for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: An induction proof consists of two important parts. Do you know what those are?

Answer (score 5):

Is it $P(1)$ true? Is it $1=2?$

When you apply induction you need two things:

- $P(1)$ holds, and
- If $P(n)$ is true then $P(n+1)$ holds.

In your case the first condition fails.

Answer (score 3):

The how of a *Proof by Induction* works is often explained by analogy to "showing that a chain of dominos will fall."

You have successfully shown that if *any* tile is tipped, then the *subsequent* tile in the chain will also tip. $$\forall n\geq 1: p(n)\to p(n+1)$$

However, you have neglected to show that the first tile in the chain *can* be tipped, rather than being set up firmly against a wall; as in fact is the case.
$$\require{cancel} \xcancel{p(1)}$$